# Java-Jsp The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request

Tags: java, jsp

My error above , I did write.
Now , I have 4 my file.The problem is simple.(denetleme.jsp,BasvuruFormu.jsp,Elemanlar.java) and I want to after in BasvuruFormu.jsp to submit clicked it is going to denetleme.jsp then there applied kontrolMethod after if boolean hata = false I want to OnayYok.jsp but i cant go.

BasvuruFormu.jsp also goes after clicking on the button denetleme.jsp then Elemanlar.java check in KontrolMethod() but boolean hata = false but after freezing false, OnayYok.jsp does not go

1)denetleme.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <jsp:useBean id="kahveCekirdegi" class="com.jsp.Elemanlar" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty property="ad" name="kahveCekirdegi" />
    <jsp:setProperty property="yas" name="kahveCekirdegi" />
    </jsp:useBean>
    <%
    if(kahveCekirdegi.kontrolMethod()){
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="onay.jsp"/>
    <%
    } else {
    %>
    <jsp:forward page="OnayYok.jsp"/>
    <%
    }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

2)BasvuruFormu.jsp

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "denetleme.jsp" method = "post">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Ad
            <input type = "text" name = "ad"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Yas
            <input type = "text" name = "yas"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit" style="background-color: red; color : black;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

3)Elemanlar.java

```
   package com.jsp;

import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Elemanlar {
    private String ad;
    private String yas;
    private Hashtable<String, String> hatalar;

    public void setYas(String yas) {
        this.yas = yas;
    }

    public String getYas() {
        return this.yas;
    }

    public void setAd(String ad) {
        this.ad = ad;
    }

    public String getAd() {
        return this.ad;
    }

    public boolean kontrolMethod() {
        boolean hata = true;
        if (ad.equals("")) {
            hatalar.put("ad", "lütfen ad giriniz");
            ad = "";
            hata = false;
        }
        if (yas.equals("")) {
            hatalar.put("yas", "Lütfen geçerli bir yaş giriniz");
            yas = "";
            hata = false;
        }
        return hata;
    }

    public String getHataMesajlari(String hataCumleleri) {
        String hataMesajlari = (String) hatalar.get(hataCumleleri.trim());
        return (hataMesajlari == null) ? "" : hataMesajlari;
    }

    public void setHatalar(String formElemani, String verilenHataMesaji) {
        hatalar.put(formElemani, verilenHataMesaji);
    }
}
```

4)OnayYok.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Onay yok jsp</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Example Ad and Yas is empty photography below.

then I clicked submit

Misateke :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay6T7.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/udYKs.png

Comment: You are turkish? can you try using 'age' instead of 'ad' ? Remember java setters having trouble with fields having only two  characters.

Comment: *Correction use 'name' instead of 'ad'

Comment: PS: Works for me, if you provide input in text box. Tries to forward to onay.jsp. You can ignore the above two comments about setter with fields having only two characters not working.

Comment: Ravindra HV , I done 'name' instead of 'ad' but I taked error again.

Comment: It works for me. The null pointer is because you have not input data in text box.